# What are the names of Lord Srinivasa residing in the seven hills of Tirupathi?

Tags: venkateshwara, tirupati

Tirupathi consists of seven hills. What are the names of the individual seven  hills and what are the synopsis of these hills? What are the names of the five Srinivasans residing in these seven hills?